# Devise Issue - Allow users to edit without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using a user scope controller generated by devise to pass additional attributes.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_action :sign_up_params, only: [:create]
 before_action :account_update_params, only: [:update

 protected

  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :cpf])
  end

  def account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :cpf, :birth_date, :phone, :gender])
  end

 def update_resource(resource, params)
   resource.update_without_password(params)
 end

end
```

The routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations}
```

Everything was working until include the **update_resource(resource, params)** method to the controller and remove the **current_password field** at the view, as suggested https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

After this change I can edit every additional fields (first_name, last_name...etc) except the password. The password change doesn't persists. Any idea?

Rails version: 5.0.0.1
Devise version: 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

In the `account_update_params` method you need to add your `password` and `password_confirmation`.

```
def account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :cpf, :birth_date, :phone, :gender, :password, :password_confirmation])
end
```

Comment: Any errors in your development log while updating Password

Comment: No, after I edit the password and password_confirmation fields at the edit view I'm redirected to the root with the sucess message, but the new password doesn't pass. 

The log just shows -  Completed 401 Unauthorized in 259ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)